# Prolog countDown

Tags: recursion, prolog, countdown

Hello i try to write recursion that count down like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkevn.png)

in prolog language

i tried to do some code like this:

```
down(Y,X):- Y>0,K is Y-1,down(K,X).
```

but its return "false."
i dont know why its return boolean result...
its need to insert into X the K value...
and generaly how to make a recursion that return all the time some number...

what i need to do?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 2):

It is generally bad practice to throw in side effects (as printing) into your predicates. But on the other hand, your question doesn't make it clear how you want to get the decreasing values.

Either way, here is the logic of a counter:

```
down(N, N). % the counter value
down(N, X) :-
    succ(N0, N), % one less, until you reach zero
    down(N0, X). % next counter value
```

You can then either simply query:

```
?- down(3, X).
```

or if you prefer, you can print out everything at once:

```
?- forall( down(3, X), format("X = ~d~n", [X]) ).
```

See [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/count_down.swinb) for a demo that uses SWI-Prolog's SWISH.

Some comments: the use of `succ/2` makes sure that the first argument is a non-negative integer. The use of `forall/2` for printing demonstrates how to make the side effect explicit.

Comment: @kalimero No need to thank. Give a vote and accept, as customary on Stack Overflow.

Comment: s(X) for using `succ/2`!

Answer (score 2):

Missing the [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) answer? Here you go!

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- X in 0..5, labeling([down], [X]).
   X = 5
;  X = 4
;  X = 3
;  X = 2
;  X = 1
;  X = 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Boris's answer using [`succ/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#succ) you could also utilize [`between/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#between) like this:

```
down(N, X) :-
   N0 is -N,
   between(N0, 0, X0),
   X is -X0.
```

Sample query:

```
?- down(3, X).
X = 3 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

`false` is not a Boolean result returned by your rule. It's a result returned by Prolog interpreter itself indicating that it cannot find an answer to your query.

Your `down` rule says what to do when `Y` is above zero, but it does not say what to do when `Y` reaches zero or goes below. In "Prolog speak" your rule is said to be missing the *base clause*.

Once you add the base clause, your rule would succeed:

```
down(Y,_) :- Y < 0.

down(Y,X):-
    Y>=0,
    write(X), write(' = '), write(Y), nl,
    K is Y-1,
    down(K,X).
```

All you need to do now is to ensure that your recursive rule prints something ([demo](http://ideone.com/vQHw2a)).

Comment: I might be wrong but there is almost certainly a bug in your program. You check `Y > 0`, you always subtract 1, and you check `Y < 0`. `Y` should be exactly 0 at some point?

Comment: @Boris You are right, since OP wants 0 in the output, I needed to modify the second clause to use `>=` instead of `>`. Thanks!